# PHP from associative array to User Class

Tags: php, arrays, object, associative-array

I know that I can cast an associative array to object doing this:

```
$user = (object) $_POST["user"];
```

I have a class User that has method getName, getEmail etc.
If I do

```
$user = (object) $_POST["user"];
$user->getName();
```

It gives this error

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method stdClass::getName()
```

Can I do something like this?

```
$user = (user) $_POST["user"];
```

Thank you

Comment: Hello ! it's possible to post a dump of $_POST ?
What is name of your user class ?

Comment: You cannot cast to any class (object) except stdClass. @Shogunivar's answer seem to me the way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not directly. What you could do is make a new user and set all the info in the constructor of your user class

```
Class User {
   public $name;
   public $otherData;

   function __construct ($userdata) {
      $name = $userdata['name'];
      $otherData = $userdata['otherData'];
   }

   function GetName() {
      return $name;
   }

}
```

Then you could call it like this:
`$user = new User($_POST["user"]);`

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this

```
<?php
  Class User{
      protected $name;
      public function setName($name){
         $this->name = $name;
      }
      public function getName(){
         return $this->name;
      }
  }
$arr = ["name"=>"Niklesh"];
$abc = new User;
$abc->setName($arr["name"]);
var_dump($abc);
var_dump($abc->getName());
?>
```

Demo : https://eval.in/765496